# Get div with class and style property jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have div with class name and width property ,How do i select html of this div

```
<div class="FL MBL" style="width:430px;">
</div>
```

How do i select html through jquery

Comment: which is the class attribute you have? whether there will be multiple elements with those classes

Comment: only with the class `$('.FL.MBL')` - it gets elements with classes `FL` and `MBL`

Comment: I want to select div that have classes FL MBL and have width:430px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check for the style attribute value along with class attributes

If the style attribute will have the value as `width:430px;` then

```
$('.FL.MBL[style="width:430px;"]')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BMDCL/)

else

```
$('.FL.MBL').filter(function(){
    return this.style.width == '430px'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yMSBZ/)

Comment: I don't want to filter first.. i want to select directly through any selector..if possible

Comment: you had a `;` inside the `style` attribute value try `$('div.MT10.brd[style="width:373px"]').html();`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select 'style' attribute, you can use

```
var width = $('.FL MBL').css('width');
```

if you want to change style property

```
$('.FL MBL').css('width','100px');
```